# SlideDrawer in android always apper as transparent , how can i set background and avoid transparent

Tags: android, slidingdrawer

SlideDrawer in android always appear as transparent , how can i set background and avoid transparent.
here is the code of SlidingDrawer control i try to set this   android:background="@drawable/menubg" 
but still appear as transparent.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <SlidingDrawer xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/SlidingDrawer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:content="@+id/contentLayout"
        android:handle="@+id/slideButton"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dip"
        >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/slideButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/menubtnup" >
        </Button>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/contentLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:background="@drawable/menubg" >

            <ScrollView
                android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:weightSum="3" >

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/Button01"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:background="@drawable/ind_slc" />

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/Button02"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:background="@drawable/rec_slc" />

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/button1"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:background="@drawable/about_slc" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:weightSum="3" >

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/Button01"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:background="@drawable/fav_slc" />

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/Button02"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:background="@drawable/request_slc" />

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/button1"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:background="@drawable/subscripe_slc" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:weightSum="3" >

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/Button01"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:background="@drawable/tell_slc" />

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/Button02"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:background="@drawable/sponser_slc" />

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/button1"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:background="@drawable/settings_slc" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </ScrollView>
        </RelativeLayout>

    </SlidingDrawer>
```

Can any one help me?

Comment: have you tried using hash codes for colors

Comment: instead of your drawable

Comment: I understand the issue , I try to use it as separated Layout then include it in any layout , but when i try to build it in each Layout .

Comment: try placing the whole stuff inside some layout  and change its background color...but keep in mind do not set android:background for sliding drawer...

Answer (score 0):

you can use some other layout and place your every control within it...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="somevalue" >
<SlidingDrawer 
    android:id="@+id/SlidingDrawer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:content="@+id/contentLayout"
    android:handle="@+id/slideButton"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dip"
    >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/slideButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/menubtnup" >
    </Button>
    ...
    ...
    ...    //more of your code
   </SlidingDrawer>
  </LinearLayout>
```

change only the background of parent linear layout to value you like...
give this a try...tell if it works